# Average same value in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I have this dataframe as below:

```
  time       power hr    fr    VE   VO2  VCO2 id               percentage
  1 00:15    25    90    24    20   632   549 LM01-PRD-S1              10
  2 00:28    25    92    23    21   679   597 LM01-PRD-S1              10
  3 00:44    25    93    22    21   675   607 LM01-PRD-S1              10
  4 01:00    25    93    20    19   680   577 LM01-PRD-S1              10
  5 01:15    40    96    20    22   745   660 LM01-PRD-S1              16
  6 01:29    40    98    21    22   764   675 LM01-PRD-S1              16
  7 01:44    40   100    21    22   789   703 LM01-PRD-S1              16
  8 01:59    40   100    20    23   805   734 LM01-PRD-S1              16
  9 02:15    55   105    22    26   911   843 LM01-PRD-S1              22
 10 02:30    55   105    20    25   881   831 LM01-PRD-S1              22
 11 02:43    55   109    19    25   895   847 LM01-PRD-S1              22
 12 02:57    55   112    21    25   908   868 LM01-PRD-S1              22
 13 03:14    70   120    21    28   981   947 LM01-PRD-S1              29
 14 03:29    70   120    21    29  1044  1021 LM01-PRD-S1              29
 15 03:43    70   122    22    27  1066  1031 LM01-PRD-S1              29
 16 03:58    70   127    19    30  1136  1122 LM01-PRD-S1              29
 17 04:15    85   130    20    32  1181  1218 LM01-PRD-S1              35
 18 04:29    85   141    21    32  1194  1216 LM01-PRD-S1              35
 19 04:42    85   139    22    34  1231  1295 LM01-PRD-S1              35
 20 04:58    85   139    19    32  1193  1268 LM01-PRD-S1              35
 21 05:12   100   139    21    31  1192  1274 LM01-PRD-S1              41
 22 05:30   100   146    21    38  1363  1460 LM01-PRD-S1              41
 23 05:45   100   150    28    50  1551  1801 LM01-PRD-S1              41
 24 05:57   100   148    30    51  1499  1810 LM01-PRD-S1              41
 25 06:14   115   150    30    55  1564  1883 LM01-PRD-S1              47
 26 06:30   115   153    31    56  1544  1892 LM01-PRD-S1              47
 27 06:44   115   157    33    59  1545  2012 LM01-PRD-S1              47
 28 06:55   115   157    34    62  1647  2091 LM01-PRD-S1              47
 29 00:15    35   102    16    18   659   576 LB02-PRD-S1              14
 30 00:28    35   101    17    19   729   613 LB02-PRD-S1              14
 31 00:44    35   105    15    28   977   851 LB02-PRD-S1              14
 32 00:59    35    96    16    28   886   852 LB02-PRD-S1              14
 33 01:12    50    90    16    16   593   504 LB02-PRD-S1              20
 34 01:28    50   106    18    17   737   552 LB02-PRD-S1              20
 35 01:44    50   108    19    23  1053   775 LB02-PRD-S1              20
 36 01:59    50   117    17    30  1236  1008 LB02-PRD-S1              20
 37 02:13    65   113    18    29  1181   983 LB02-PRD-S1              27
 38 02:29    65   114    15    31  1167  1016 LB02-PRD-S1              27
 39 02:44    65   118    16    31  1167  1052 LB02-PRD-S1              27
 40 02:59    65   114    17    28  1104   967 LB02-PRD-S1              27
 41 03:13    80   120    17    35  1318  1172 LB02-PRD-S1              33
 42 03:29    80   117    16    32  1236  1153 LB02-PRD-S1              33
 43 03:43    80   122    17    31  1168  1094 LB02-PRD-S1              33
 44 03:57    80   122    17    34  1312  1205 LB02-PRD-S1              33
 45 04:14    95   126    18    37  1311  1274 LB02-PRD-S1              39
 46 04:28    95   129    18    35  1248  1201 LB02-PRD-S1              39
 47 04:44    95   131    15    33  1275  1196 LB02-PRD-S1              39
 48 04:57    95   134    18    39  1444  1381 LB02-PRD-S1              39
 49 05:13   110   134    19    43  1539  1472 LB02-PRD-S1              45
 50 05:29   110   136    19    41  1417  1406 LB02-PRD-S1              45
 51 05:44   110   137    20    43  1496  1437 LB02-PRD-S1              45
 52 06:00   110   139    20    44  1561  1539 LB02-PRD-S1              45
 53 06:14   125   142    21    46  1561  1560 LB02-PRD-S1              51
 54 06:28   125   146    21    46  1535  1552 LB02-PRD-S1              51
 55 06:44   125   148    23    51  1698  1703 LB02-PRD-S1              51
 56 07:00   125   150    23    53  1725  1776 LB02-PRD-S1              51
 57 07:13   140   151    22    52  1726  1760 LB02-PRD-S1              57
 58 07:29   140   151    23    53  1713  1763 LB02-PRD-S1              57
 59 07:44   140   153    25    55  1807  1836 LB02-PRD-S1              57
 60 07:59   140   155    26    58  1897  1941 LB02-PRD-S1              57
 61 08:15   155   153    26    59  1929  1963 LB02-PRD-S1              63
 62 08:29   155   157    26    57  1843  1908 LB02-PRD-S1              63
 63 08:44   155   160    28    65  1942  2065 LB02-PRD-S1              63
 64 09:00   155   164    26    64  2011  2131 LB02-PRD-S1              63
 65 09:14   170   166    26    65  2048  2178 LB02-PRD-S1              69
 66 09:30   170   166    26    64  2069  2171 LB02-PRD-S1              69
 67 09:45   170   169    25    64  2165  2269 LB02-PRD-S1              69
 68 10:00   170   169    28    76  2328  2539 LB02-PRD-S1              69
 69 10:14   185   169    30    76  2189  2449 LB02-PRD-S1              76
 70 10:29   185   171    29    73  2225  2411 LB02-PRD-S1              76
 71 10:44   185   171    29    68  2170  2292 LB02-PRD-S1              76
 72 10:59   185   171    31    82  2458  2712 LB02-PRD-S1              76
 73 11:14   200   171    33    89  2443  2780 LB02-PRD-S1              82
 74 11:29   200   173    33    87  2465  2784 LB02-PRD-S1              82
 75 11:44   200   176    32    88  2536  2853 LB02-PRD-S1              82
 76 12:00   200   176    34    93  2571  2899 LB02-PRD-S1              82
 77 12:15   215   176    36    98  2529  2924 LB02-PRD-S1              88
 78 12:30   215   179    36   105  2602  3087 LB02-PRD-S1              88
 79 12:45   215   179    39   111  2795  3282 LB02-PRD-S1              88
 80 12:59   215   181    40   118  2679  3240 LB02-PRD-S1              88
 81 13:15   230   179    40   113  2649  3160 LB02-PRD-S1              94
 82 13:29   230   179    41   111  2601  3055 LB02-PRD-S1              94
 83 13:45   230   176    42   116  2639  3129 LB02-PRD-S1              94
 84 13:59   230   181    43   126  2683  3277 LB02-PRD-S1              94
 85 14:15   245   181    47   123  2597  3160 LB02-PRD-S1             100
 86 14:30   245   181    48   128  2482  3122 LB02-PRD-S1             100
 87 00:15    25   101    20    18   712   584 GC03-PRD-S1              10
 88 00:30    25    99    20    17   673   551 GC03-PRD-S1              10
 89 00:45    25    97    20    17   686   559 GC03-PRD-S1              10
 90 00:58    25    96    20    16   639   524 GC03-PRD-S1              10
 91 01:13    40    99    19    16   647   518 GC03-PRD-S1              16
 92 01:27    40   105    19    16   669   543 GC03-PRD-S1              16
 93 01:45    40   107    21    18   723   598 GC03-PRD-S1              16
 94 01:59    40   107    25    19   746   605 GC03-PRD-S1              16
 95 02:12    55   109    23    20   775   645 GC03-PRD-S1              22
 96 02:27    55   111    20    20   780   671 GC03-PRD-S1              22
 97 02:41    55   116    21    21   811   710 GC03-PRD-S1              22
 98 02:59    55   113    17    22   858   765 GC03-PRD-S1              22
 99 03:13    70   117    21    23   900   789 GC03-PRD-S1              29
100 03:30    70   117    20    23   953   843 GC03-PRD-S1              29
101 03:45    70   120    20    25   980   882 GC03-PRD-S1              29
102 03:58    70   122    22    26  1000   916 GC03-PRD-S1              29
103 04:14    85   122    23    27  1049   961 GC03-PRD-S1              35
104 04:29    85   126    23    28  1072   992 GC03-PRD-S1              35
105 04:43    85   131    22    29  1110  1056 GC03-PRD-S1              35
106 04:59    85   130    22    30  1066  1047 GC03-PRD-S1              35
107 05:13   100   129    21    28  1166  1057 GC03-PRD-S1              41
108 05:29   100   137    27    34  1346  1247 GC03-PRD-S1              41
109 05:45   100   137    22    34  1272  1261 GC03-PRD-S1              41
110 06:00   100   136    20    33  1222  1235 GC03-PRD-S1              41
111 06:13   115   139    23    36  1321  1321 GC03-PRD-S1              47
112 06:29   115   142    23    37  1340  1377 GC03-PRD-S1              47
113 06:43   115   144    24    38  1362  1418 GC03-PRD-S1              47
114 06:59   115   150    27    44  1470  1579 GC03-PRD-S1              47
115 07:14   130   151    27    45  1466  1618 GC03-PRD-S1              53
116 07:30   130   153    31    54  1686  1875 GC03-PRD-S1              53
117 07:44   130   155    33    59  1679  1998 GC03-PRD-S1              53
118 07:59   130   157    33    59  1676  2021 GC03-PRD-S1              53
119 08:13   145   157    33    61  1700  2041 GC03-PRD-S1              59
120 08:29   145   160    35    64  1764  2120 GC03-PRD-S1              59
121 08:44   145   160    36    67  1765  2182 GC03-PRD-S1              59
122 08:59   145   162    40    71  1762  2208 GC03-PRD-S1              59
123 00:01   145   162    39    69  1754  2208 GC03-PRD-S1              59
124 00:15    60   127    27    40  1267  1274 GT04-PRD-S1              24
125 00:29    60   131    29    40  1264  1274 GT04-PRD-S1              24
126 00:44    60   133    30    40  1281  1298 GT04-PRD-S1              24
127 00:58    60   134    29    42  1304  1360 GT04-PRD-S1              24
128 01:14    80   134    28    40  1274  1324 GT04-PRD-S1              33
129 01:30    80   137    28    40  1337  1335 GT04-PRD-S1              33
130 01:45    80   144    29    45  1485  1501 GT04-PRD-S1              33
131 02:00    80   144    30    50  1573  1630 GT04-PRD-S1              33
132 02:14   100   148    30    47  1380  1478 GT04-PRD-S1              41
133 02:29   100   150    30    49  1520  1576 GT04-PRD-S1              41
134 02:45   100   153    31    50  1553  1589 GT04-PRD-S1              41
135 02:59   100   151    31    55  1735  1818 GT04-PRD-S1              41
136 03:13   120   153    32    65  1905  2146 GT04-PRD-S1              49
137 03:28   120   151    32    62  1748  2026 GT04-PRD-S1              49
138 03:44   120   160    31    61  1799  2041 GT04-PRD-S1              49
139 03:58   120   160    30    64  1810  2105 GT04-PRD-S1              49
140 04:13   140   164    33    73  1895  2314 GT04-PRD-S1              57
141 04:28   140   162    33    72  1966  2345 GT04-PRD-S1              57
142 04:44   140   166    36    79  2021  2470 GT04-PRD-S1              57
143 05:00   140   166    35    76  2022  2450 GT04-PRD-S1              57
144 05:14   160   164    37    78  2115  2491 GT04-PRD-S1              65
145 05:29   160   169    40    82  2147  2583 GT04-PRD-S1              65
146 05:44   160   169    38    83  2190  2647 GT04-PRD-S1              65
147 05:59   160   173    38    85  2202  2713 GT04-PRD-S1              65
148 06:15   180   171    38    88  2332  2837 GT04-PRD-S1              73
149 06:29   180   171    41    95  2321  2937 GT04-PRD-S1              73
150 06:45   180   176    39    94  2358  2994 GT04-PRD-S1              73
151 06:59   180   176    42   104  2339  3086 GT04-PRD-S1              73
152 07:09   200   176    44   105  2444  3186 GT04-PRD-S1              82
```

When we have a look in the `percentage` column, there is the same value each four rows. After removing all rows where the value is not repeated 4 times, I would like to average these four rows in the `percentage` column BUT within each `id`.

I tried this

`df <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  aggregate(df, by=list(df$percentage), FUN = mean)`

But it gave me that an error message.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Some values are present more than 4 times. Also, some are present less then 4 times. How to deal with these?

Comment: Which columns do you want to average ? `power`,  `hr`  etc ?

Comment: @tmfmnk, you are right ! So before that, I proposed to delete all the rows where the value is not present 4 times. Do you have a solution for that too? I edited my question

Comment: @Ronak Shah, the `percentage` column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try something like this

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(len_seq = rep(rle(percentage)$lengths, rle(percentage)$lengths)) %>% 
  filter(len_seq == 4) %>% 
  mutate(seq_id = rep(1:(n()/4), each = 4)) %>% 
  group_by(id, seq_id) %>% 
  summarize_at(vars(power:VCO2,percentage), function(x) mean(x)) %>% 
  select(-seq_id)
```

Will give:

```
# A tibble: 36 x 8
# Groups:   id [4]
   id          power    hr    fr    VE   VO2  VCO2 percentage
   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 GC03-PRD-S1    25  98.2  20    17    678.  554.         10
 2 GC03-PRD-S1    40 104.   21    17.2  696.  566          16
 3 GC03-PRD-S1    55 112.   20.2  20.8  806   698.         22
 4 GC03-PRD-S1    70 119    20.8  24.2  958.  858.         29
 5 GC03-PRD-S1    85 127.   22.5  28.5 1074. 1014          35
 6 GC03-PRD-S1   100 135.   22.5  32.2 1252. 1200          41
 7 GC03-PRD-S1   115 144.   24.2  38.8 1373. 1424.         47
 8 GC03-PRD-S1   130 154    31    54.2 1627. 1878          53
 9 GT04-PRD-S1    60 131.   28.8  40.5 1279  1302.         24
10 GT04-PRD-S1    80 140.   28.8  43.8 1417. 1448.         33
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Comment: I just tried it now, and it is working very well ! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id, percentage) %>%
 filter(n() == 4) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 select(id, percentage)
```

It is not computing the average but selecting the first row per value per ID as the average from the same values is exactly the same.

```
   id          percentage
   <chr>            <int>
 1 GC03-PRD-S1         10
 2 GC03-PRD-S1         16
 3 GC03-PRD-S1         22
 4 GC03-PRD-S1         29
 5 GC03-PRD-S1         35
 6 GC03-PRD-S1         41
 7 GC03-PRD-S1         47
 8 GC03-PRD-S1         53
 9 GT04-PRD-S1         24
10 GT04-PRD-S1         33
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Again, you are right, it is not computing the average, but keeping the first row of each cycle. It is not the best option. But thank you!

Comment: Actually, if you need the mean from the same values, then it is a very good option as you don't need to calculate the mean :)

Comment: When we average the "four rows", the aim is to have the mean of each respective column. In your example, it is removing the row 2,3,4 and keeping the first one. Thanks!

Comment: Sure it is, but isn't `mean(c(10, 10, 10, 10))` exactly the same as `c(10, 10, 10, 10)[1]`? :)

Comment: It is the mean of 10,10,10,10, but if you have a look on the column `VO2`, it should be also the mean of each value. But in your example, it is the first value of each four-row.

Comment: do you want to compute the mean of the other columns as well? Not only percentage?

Comment: @Roccer, exactly! The mean of each row, based on the average of the "four-row" in the `percentage` column. Thank you!

Comment: @MaxStudent, did the answer below solve your problem?

Comment: @Roccer, I just tried it now, and it is working very well ! Thank you!